# PHP | How would I create a "plugin system" to inject content/HTML onto my page?

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to create a function that can inject HTML in between certain div tags using PHP.

For example lets say I have the function with the following parameters. `add_html('<div class = "greeting">', 'hello')`

How would I make it so that the text `hello` was added inside of `<div class = "greeting">` like so: `<div class = "greeting">hello</div>` My goal is to use PHP for this. How would I go about implementing this? What would be the most simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: You want the plugin to be able to call `add_menu_option`? For that to happen, the plugin needs to be given control of the process at some point. So, you could use a "plugin hook" such that the CMS calls a known function in the plugin which can then do this sort of call, or else you have an "event hook" where the plugin can register a number of listeners for different when it's loaded, and then your CMS triggers listeners registered for specific events at different times in its process. Does that context help any?

Comment: If not, then I don't know that we can give much more help. It's a very foundational question, and the solution will very much depend on how you want to structure your system, what code you already have, etc., probably more information than can reasonably be given here.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have edited my question to something a bit more clear.

Comment: My response was based on the expectation that you want to have WordPress style plugins that can be enabled or disabled, and if they are enabled then they can add their own content to pages, add menu items specific to their functionality, that sort of thing. If what you're looking for is just something that formats text into HTML or builds simple menus, then the word "plugin" is not relevant.

Comment: @GregSchmidt That is what im looking for.

Comment: Sorry, which "that" is what you're looking for? WordPress style plugins, or something that just formats text into HTML?

Comment: WordPress style plugins @GregSchmidt

Answer (score 0):

A function could be like so:

```
<?php

function add_div($class, $content) {
    return sprintf('<div class="%s">%s</div>', $class, $content);
}

echo add_div('foo', 'Hello Earth!');
```

Output:

```
<div class="foo">Hello Earth!</div>
```

But it doesn't really save you much typing.

Comment: But perhaps this isn't what you mean,  and you are trying to manipulate the DOM - inserting content into existing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the particulars of it, but the fundamental issue remains unanswerable with any kind of specifics that it seems you're looking for. I am struggling to even express how many variables there are in what you're asking. I'm putting this as an answer, not because it answers your question, but because comments are insufficient to address it.

Your current example is that you want a "greeting" div. Okay. But where do you want it? On every page? On the home page? At the top or bottom or somewhere in between? Let's assume that your CMS has a way of knowing what overall layout is going to be used (headers, footers, menus, sidebars, etc.), and what specific template is going to be used to generate the page-specific content (text and pictures of a blog post, for example), and that you want to give your plugins a way to inject their own content into the layout right at the top of the content (above the blog text and pictures). This is now a nice, specific sort of question that StackOverflow is better at answering, instead of such a general open-ended one that you have.

Okay, let's address that particular question. Ideally, you would show your CMS code for generating a page. Let's pretend it's something like this:

```
echo $this->layout->headers();
echo $this->layout->menu();
echo $this->template->content();
echo $this->layout->footers();
```

It's probably actually more complex than that, but this will do for an example. Now, we can say that if you want to use a plugin hook architecture, you would add something like this after the `menu` call:

```
foreach ($this->plugins as $plugin) {
    if (method_exists($plugin, 'inject_pre_content')) {
        $plugin->inject_pre_content();
    }
}
```

and you would add an `inject_pre_content` function in your plugin which echoes your desired HTML.

If you wanted to use event hooks instead, then in the same place you might instead simply add:

```
$this->triggerEvent('inject_pre_content');
```

but this relies on you also incorporating an event handling framework.

Plugin hooks are, IMO, easier to build, but not as powerful.

Hope that this helps you to understand what you're up against a little bit better, and clarifies what the two main options might look like.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it has definitely helped me decide how I am going to do this.